# Is there a "geom_donothing" function in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use ggplot, I generally format my code as such:

```
ggplot() +
   geom_col() +
   geom_line() +
   scale_y_continuous()
```

This format neatly organizes the components of the plot, and RStudio lets you run all the lines by hitting `Ctrl+Enter`. If I ever want to remove a component of the plot, I can simply comment that line out, and RStudio will ignore that line.

But if I comment out the last line,

```
ggplot() +
   geom_col() +
   geom_line() +
   #scale_y_continuous()
```

I will get an error, because I did not remove the `+` after `geom_line()`. It is obviously easy to remove the `+` sign, but then I have add it back when I un-comment the last line.

It's not a huge problem, but in the process of making a plot, I inevitably forget to add or remove the `+` at least once. It is a bigger problem when working on a laptop with a small screen, where I cannot necessarily see the end of the last line.

**Is there a function in ggplot which I can add below the last line, which will be read, but will do nothing, preventing me from having to deal with the `+` signs?**

For example, Python has the `pass` statement, which acts as a filler when writing code. Does something similar exist in ggplot?

Comment: `geom_blank()` ?

Comment: `theme()` can serve the purpose as well.

Comment: @Sam - is there a particular reason you want an R function? In R I've seen two general forms of ggplot() structure creation. The trailing `+` and preceding `gp <- gp +`, interested as to why of you emboldened request for a function. For example, you could create your own empty function and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options

a. `geom_blank()`

b. `gp <- gp +`.

The `gp <- gp +` solution is my personal recommendation. It allows for simple addition and removal of ggplot components and as a byproduct gives you a `gp` gglpot structure you can interogate via RStudio:

```
gp <- ggplot()
gp <- gp + geom_col() 
gp <- gp + geom_line() 
# gp <- gp + scale_y_continuous()
gp
```

this achieves the same result as the end of line `+` without the extra superfluous function call. As an alternative, you might consider using `geom_blank()` if you have a large code base to update then the latter `geom_blank()` may be an easier choice. (This assumes you still debugging or tweaking your plots)

```
ggplot() +
geom_col() +
geom_line() +
# scale_y_continuous() +
geom_blank()
```

my sense is this is a question of aesthetics. I am not a fan of trailing `+` because of the potential for drop through to other code (line overrun). Such situations can create interesting and awkward debugging situations.

Comment: Thanks, `geom_blank()` is exactly what I was looking for. I realize that stringing code over multiple lines using `+` is somewhat odd, but that is how I prefer doing it. (This is partly due to the fact that I am working on a laptop, so horizontal space is limited.)

Comment: @sam All the documentation at https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ uses `+` over multiple lines so it doesn't strike me as "odd" (though the inconsistency between pipes and pluses can be annoying). There are some advantages to `gp <- gp +` too, particularly in interactive use or for someone learning ggplot for the first time. I would strongly suggest changing the `geom_blank()` suggestion to `NULL` for the reasons given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52371564/1895415) (avoids adding extra layers to plot and is the way ggplot was designed to work)

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot() + theme()
```

or

```
ggplot() + list()
```

or

```
ggplot() + invisible(list())
```

do nothing and do not add a layer. The last one also won't print anything if executed on its own.

Answer (score 1):

A perhaps safer option is to use `NULL`. This does literally nothing whereas `geom_blank()` adds a layer. The use of `NULL` after a ggplot chain is a [deliberate design feature](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/918438633111203841).

```r
library('ggplot2')

plot0 = ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species))

plot1 = ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species))+
#  scale_y_continuous()+
  NULL

plot2 = 
  ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species))+
#  scale_y_continuous()+
  geom_blank()


length(plot0$layers)
#> [1] 1

length(plot1$layers)
#> [1] 1

length(plot2$layers)
#> [1] 2

object.size(plot0) < object.size(plot1)
#> [1] FALSE

object.size(plot0) < object.size(plot2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: As the word of hadley this should have more upvotes! Shame it was documented on twitter rather than (as far as I can see) the docs themselves. It's worth knowing the `NULL` doesn't have to come at the end; particularly if you're adding layers programmatically it's fine to produce something like `ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 3:1), aes(x = x, y = y)) + NULL + geom_point()`